# How to create a button within a custom JavaScript/Html element that onclick performs two functions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a webinar with EverWebinar and I'm passing the url parameter codes from EverWebinar over to my custom Thank-You page on ClickFunnels.... here's where it gets tricky! On the thank-you page, I have a secondary opt-in for their phone number, but they also need an option to say "no" and opt out, while still passing on the URL parameters regardless of which of the two pages they go to.

What I did was I grabbed the parameters and then I setup the two variables in Nexturl3 and Nexturl4 as seen below in the header code:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var newParam = getParameterByName('wj_lead_unique_link_live_room')
var nextURL3 = ('https://raisingcapitalforrealestate.com/ty-confirmation\?wj_lead_unique_link_live_room\=' + newParam);
var nextURL4 = ('https://raisingcapitalforrealestate.com/you-are-registered\?wj_lead_unique_link_live_room\=' + newParam);  
</script>
```

Then, on the "deny button" I used this code (which works perfectly well)

```
<div class="de elBTN elAlign_center elMargin0 ui-droppable de-editable" id="tmp_button-86409" data-de-type="button" data-de-editing="false" data-title="button" data-ce="false" data-trigger="none" data-animate="fade" data-delay="500" style="margin-top: 10px; outline: none; cursor: pointer; display: block;" aria-disabled="false" data-elbuttontype="1">
<a onclick="location.href=nextURL4;" class="elButton elButtonSize1 elButtonColor1 elButtonRounded elButtonPadding2 elBtnVP_10 elButtonCorner3 elBtnHP_25 elBTN_b_1 elButtonNoShadow elButtonTxtColor1 elButtonFluid" style="color: rgb(45, 45, 45); font-weight: 600; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 12px;">
<span class="elButtonMain">No thanks... I don't want to learn from these 10 capital raising all stars</span>
<span class="elButtonSub"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

But this is where I'm having issues - on the SUBMIT button (code below). I'm trying to perform the "Submit Page" function, but also to send to nextURL3. When I use both functions inside the "onclick" it does neither function (so maybe I'm calling it wrong?) - but when I just do onclick=;location.href=nextURL3;" it "works" by taking me to that page upon button press...but the phone number never gets submitted.

(non-working version)

```
<div class="de elBTN elAlign_center elMargin0 ui-droppable de-editable" id="tmp_button-86409" data-de-type="button" data-de-editing="false" data-title="button" data-ce="false" data-trigger="none" data-animate="fade" data-delay="500" style="margin-top: 20px; outline: none; cursor: pointer; display: block;" aria-disabled="false" data-elbuttontype="1">
<a onclick="#submit-form;location.href=nextURL3;" class="elButton elButtonSize1 elButtonColor1 elButtonRounded elButtonPadding2 elBtnVP_10 elButtonCorner3 elBtnHP_25 elBTN_b_1 elButtonShadowN1 elButtonTxtColor1 elButtonFull" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 600; background-color: rgb(228, 59, 44); font-size: 18px;">
<span class="elButtonMain"><i class="fa_prepended fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Send Me The Interviews NOW!<i class="fa_appended fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></span>
<span class="elButtonSub"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

Any help would be amazing :) Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Just a heads up -- **Java** and **JavaScript** are two completely different languages that merely have similar sounding names; it is best not to conflate the two.

Comment: @AlexanderNied thanks, I think i was just so tired of typing by the time i finished the post I wasn't paying attention at all. :) thanks for lookin' out.

Answer (score 0):

**First, declare you functions as usual:**

```
function example_Function_1()
{
... Some codes here.
}

function example_Function_2()
{
... Some codes here.
}
```

**then user this JQuery code to execute both of them:**

```
$('#Your_Button_Id').on('click',function(){

   example_Function_1();
   example_Function_2();

});
```